# viewModel/model not saving boolean value - android

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, android-viewmodel

I am trying to make a call to an endpoint to onboard a user to an app. For some reason the boolean values are not being stored in my user object. The other items are fine. I'm missing something but I simply cannot see where. I'd really appreciate another set of eyes to help point out where I'm off.

Thanks!!

Here is my User model

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Parcelize
class User(
    var userID: Int = 0,
    var email: String = "",
    var name: String = "",
    var termsAccepted: String = "",
    var resetCode: String = "",
    var userType: Int = 0,
    var messageNotifications: String = "0",
    var matchesNotifications: String = "0",
    var timeCreated: String = "",
    var timeUpdated: String = "",
    var zipCode: String = "",
    var lat: Double = 0.0,
    var lng: Double = 0.0,
    var distance: Int = 1,
    var profilePic: String = "",
    @com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize(using = NumericBooleanDeserializer::class)
    var isBreeder: Boolean = false, // <---------------
    @com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize(using = NumericBooleanDeserializer::class)
    var autoShare: Boolean = false, // <---------------
    @com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize(using = NumericBooleanDeserializer::class)
    var isSearching: Boolean = false, // <---------------
    var location: String = "",
    var password: String = "",
    var confirmPassword: String = "",
    var newPassword: String = "",
    var breeds: String = "",
    var proximity: Double = 5.0,
    @com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize(using = NumericBooleanDeserializer::class)
    var hasDog: Boolean = false,  // <---------------
    //@com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize(using = NumericBooleanDeserializer::class)
    //var dogs: Boolean = false
    var dogs: ArrayList<Dog> = ArrayList()
) : Parcelable {
}
```

This is the fragment

```
enum class InfoTypes {
    BREEDERS, SHARE_CONTACTS
}

class PersonalInfoFragment : BaseFragment(), View.OnClickListener,
    AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    private lateinit var _binding: FragmentPersonalInfoBinding
    private lateinit var dialogUtil: AlertDialogUtil
    private lateinit var viewModel: OnboardingDogViewModel
    private var loginObserver: Observer<User>? = null
    private var personalInfoObserver: Observer<PersonalInfoModel>? = null
    private var check: Boolean = false
    private var user: User = getUserPref()
    private var dog: Dog = Dog()
    private lateinit var breedSpinner: AutoCompleteTextView
    private lateinit var breedAdapter: NoFilterAdapter
    private lateinit var seedViewModel: SeedViewModel
    private var breedList: List<SeedBreed> = ArrayList()
    private var appState: AppState = AppState()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val factory = OnboardingDogViewModelFactory(OnboardingRepo(), dog, user)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, factory)[OnboardingDogViewModel::class.java]

        val seedFactory = SeedViewModelFactory(SeedRepo())
        seedViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, seedFactory)[SeedViewModel::class.java]
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = FragmentPersonalInfoBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        dialogUtil = AlertDialogUtil(WeakReference(requireActivity()))
        _binding.acBreedSpinner.isEnabled = false
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return _binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        initSpinner()
        initView()
        setOnClickListeners()
    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    private fun initView() {
        _binding.cbBreeder.setOnTouchListener(OnTouchListener { v, event ->
            onPressInfoIcon(v, event, InfoTypes.BREEDERS)
        })
        _binding.cbShareContact.setOnTouchListener(OnTouchListener { v, event ->
            onPressInfoIcon(v, event, InfoTypes.SHARE_CONTACTS)
        })

        _binding.etFirstName.afterTextChanged {
            viewModel.user.name = it
            setStringPref(FIRST_NAME, viewModel.user.name!!)
            _binding.btnNext.isEnabled = viewModel.user.validate()
        }
        _binding.cbShareContact.setOnCheckedChangeListener { compoundButton, b ->
            //viewModel.personalInfo.shareContactInformation = b
            viewModel.user.autoShare = b
        }

        _binding.cbBreeder.setOnCheckedChangeListener { compoundButton, b ->
            viewModel.user.isBreeder = b // <-------------------------- HERE
            Log.d(TAG, "initView: user isBreeder = ${viewModel.user.isBreeder}")
            appState.isBreeder = b
            setAppState(appState)
        }

        _binding.cbSearchingPuppies.setOnCheckedChangeListener { compoundButton, b ->
            viewModel.user.isSearching = b  // <-------------------------- HERE
            _binding.acBreedSpinner.isEnabled = b
//            appState.isPuppies = b
//            if (!b) {
//                appState.accountType = AppState.OWNER
//            } else {
//                appState.accountType = AppState.DOG
//            }
//            setAppState(appState)
            _binding.btnNext.isEnabled = viewModel.user.validate();
        }
    }
    fun initSpinner() {
        breedSpinner = _binding.acBreedSpinner
        val breeds = listIterator()
        breedAdapter = NoFilterAdapter(requireContext(), R.layout.mb_spinner_item, breeds)

        if (!seedViewModel.allBreeds.hasActiveObservers()) {
            seedViewModel.allBreeds.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, breedObserver)
        }
        breedSpinner.setAdapter(breedAdapter)
        _binding.acBreedSpinner.onItemSelectedListener = this 

        _binding.acBreedSpinner.onItemClickListener = AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
                av, v, pos, len ->
            viewModel.dog.breed = breedList[pos].breed
            viewModel.dog.breedId = breedList[pos].breedSeedID

            _binding.acBreedSpinner.setText(breedList[pos].breed)
            Log.d(DogProfileFormFragment.TAG, "onItemSelected: ${viewModel.dog.breed}")
        }
    }

    //function for converting breedlist
    // the drop down will be for visual purposes = w
    private fun listIterator(): ArrayList<String> {
        val tempList = ArrayList<String>()
        breedList.forEachIndexed { index, seedBreed ->
            tempList.add(seedBreed.breed)
        }
        return tempList
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        when (v!!.id) {
            _binding.btnNext.id -> {
                // go to next activity when there's a name?
                setUserPref(viewModel.user)  // <-------------------------- HERE
                (requireActivity() as BaseActivity).navigateTo(
                    R.id.locationProximityFragment,
                    R.anim.fade_in,
                    R.anim.fade_out,
                    R.anim.fade_in,
                    R.anim.fade_out,
                )
            }
            _binding.acBreedSpinner.id -> {
                _binding.acBreedSpinner.showDropDown()
            }
        }
    }


    private fun setOnClickListeners() {
        _binding.btnNext.setOnClickListener(this::onClick)
        _binding.acBreedSpinner.setOnClickListener(this::onClick)
    }



    override fun onItemSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, p3: Long) {
        when (p0!!.id) {
            _binding.acBreedSpinner.id -> {
                viewModel.dog.breed = breedList[position].breed
                viewModel.dog.breedId = breedList[position].breedSeedID
                Log.d(DogProfileFormFragment.TAG, "onItemSelected: ${viewModel.dog.breed}")
            }
        }
    }
    override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?) {
    }

    fun onPressInfoIcon(v: View, event: MotionEvent, infoTypes: InfoTypes): Boolean {
        if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if (event.rawX >= _binding.cbBreeder.getRight() - _binding.cbBreeder.getCompoundDrawables()
                    .get(DRAWABLE_RIGHT).getBounds().width()
            ) {
                val message: String = if (infoTypes === InfoTypes.BREEDERS) {
                    getString(R.string.breeder_info)
                } else {
                    getString(R.string.share_contact_info)
                }
                dialogUtil.infoDialog(message, getString(R.string.okay), null)!!.show()
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }

    private val breedObserver: Observer<List<SeedBreed>> = Observer {
        if (it != null)
            breedList = it
        val tempList = listIterator()
        breedAdapter.updateList(tempList) // add this method to NoFilterAdapter
    }

    companion object {
        const val TAG = "PERSONAL_INFO_FRAGMENT"
    }
}
```

SharedPreferences

```
fun setStringPref(pref : String, str: String){
    val editor = SharedPref.edit()
    editor.putString(pref,str).apply()
}
fun getUserPref(): User {
    val u = getStringPref(PREF_USER)
    if(u == ""){
        return User()
    }
    return mapper.readValue(u, User::class.java)
}

fun setUserPref(user: User) {
    val userString = mapper.writeValueAsString(user)
    setStringPref(PREF_USER, userString)
}
```

logging out one of the booleans, it is true when I set it, but it reverts to false when I continue to the next fragment

```
2022-07-17 12:34:35.783 26910-26910/com.ns804.matchbreed D/PERSONAL_INFO_FRAGMENT: initView: user isBreeder = true
2022-07-17 12:34:45.223 26910-26910/com.ns804.matchbreed D/LocationProximityFragment: onCreate: false, false
```

next fragment

```
 override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: ${viewModel.user.isBreeder}, ${viewModel.user.autoShare}")
        initViews()
        setOnClickListener()
    }
```

Comment: If you remove all the details about fragments, shared preferences, etc and just make a unit test that serializes a `User` to a string then de-serializes that string back to a `User` do you see the same issue? What happens if you remove the special annotation you have on all the `Boolean` fields?

Comment: The annotations are there for deserializing the API response. I'm not super familiar with testing

Comment: You should not need a special de-serializer for plain old boolean values (and you didn't include the custom deserializer or what library it's from in the question so nobody has any idea what it actually does - nor did you show what the JSON string you are trying to deserialize looks like). You should definitely take the time to learn how to write unit tests instead of just dumping the whole code on StackOverflow. If your special de-serializer is there to take an integer and convert it to a boolean or something, then you could pretty easily check whether it is working properly in a unit test.

Comment: The fact that 1) you have a special de-serializer just for boolean values, and 2) your boolean values aren't deserialized properly from the string you save in SharedPrefs means that's a pretty likely cause.

Comment: This seems to be purely about your (de)serialisation - and like Tyler says, the fact you have a special annotation just for `Boolean`s is suspect when they're the ones not working. But since you mentioned ``ViewModel``s, just in case you're not aware - when you're in a `Fragment` and you call `ViewModelProvider(this)` you're getting the VM stored for that specific *class* - it won't be shared with any other fragments, you'd need to pass the `Activity` or use `by navGraphViewModels` if you want to share data. You might be doing it intentionally and persisting data anyway, but just mentioning it

Comment: I will talk to my Sr dev tomorrow, just trying to get a jump on it. Thanks for the comments.